# Getting Local Photos Windows Phone 8 Emulator

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, emulation, photos

So I have taken some Photos on my windows phone emulator and I am then trying to find them in my application.
So Far I have:

```
PictureCollection CameraRollPictures;
using (var library = new MediaLibrary())
{
    //taking all albums
     PictureAlbumCollection allAlbums = library.RootPictureAlbum.Albums;
     //taking Camera Roll album separately from all album
     PictureAlbum cameraRoll = allAlbums.Where(album => album.Name == "Camera Roll").FirstOrDefault();
     // here you will get camera roll picture list
     CameraRollPictures = cameraRoll.Pictures;
}
```

But this keeps crashing because `cameraRoll = null`. Is this feature available on WP8 emulator or am I doing something wrong?

My method to get photos is from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719250/windows-phone-8-obtain-taken-photos-from-phone-library)

**EDIT**
I have also tried `album.Name == "Camera Roll"`

[image: Windows Phone Photos]

Comment: can you check if your allAlbums item is null or empty?

Comment: My allAlbums item contains a {Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.PictureAlbumCollection} but has a count of 0

Comment: But I have uploaded an image showing that there are photos that have been cached. (Sorry don't know / have time, to resize image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer was simple... My method worked perfectly but I needed to:

- go into the WMAppManifest.Xml
- go to Capabilities
- tick `ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO`

This provides read-only access to photos in the media library

Answer (score 1):

```
MediaSource mediaSource = MediaSource.GetAvailableMediaSources()
            .First((source => source.MediaSourceType == MediaSourceType.LocalDevice));
using (MediaLibrary mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary(mediaSource))
{
     PictureAlbum cameraRollAlbum = mediaLibrary.RootPictureAlbum.Albums.First((album) => album.Name == "Camera Roll");

}
```

or use [`PhotoChooserTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh394019(v=vs.105).aspx)

You can upload Images to an [`Emulator`](http://www.softwareisinthedetails.com/2012/11/add-test-images-on-windows-phone-emulator.html) as mentioned here

Comment: Sadly the MediaSource method was still returning no `PictureAlbum`'s. I can't use the PhotoChooserTask because I am using Xamarin forms and I haven't tried the last one but I will try that later