# Accessing saved image on a Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone

I am creating a camera app for the Windows Phone but when I want to retrieve my saved photo as a `BitmapImage`, nothing seems to work. I am using `IsolatedStorageSettings` to save the path of the images as shown below:

```
            Picture p = mediaLibrary.SavePictureToCameraRoll(fileName, e.ImageStream);
            if (!settings.Contains("lastImageTaken"))
            {
                //GetPath() requires using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.PhoneExtensions;
                settings.Add("lastImageTaken", p.GetPath());
            }
            else
            {
                settings["lastImageTaken"] = p.GetPath();
            }
            settings.Save();
```

then once the app starts up, I try to retrieve that last photo taken as shown below:

```
lastImageTaken = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["lastImageTaken"] as string;


            Uri uri = new System.Uri(lastImageTaken, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(uri);

            previouseImage.Source = image;

            if (image.PixelWidth < 1)
                debugText.Text += " FAILED";
```

I have also tried something like this:

```
Uri uri = new System.Uri("file:///" + lastImageTaken.Replace("\\", "/"), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

but nothing seems to display the image. The width of to image always is shown as `0` which displays a `"FAILED"` text on a debug text. `lastImageTaken` is shown as `C:\Data\Users\Public\Camera Roll\SMCA_jpg.jpg`

I have also added the capabilities of `ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO`

Comment: Can you check if your image is really saved in isolated storage with some tools?

Comment: I am saving to camera roll

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are saving the image to CameraRoll, but trying to retrieve image from IsolatedStorage. Those are two different storage areas, and they are accessed differently.

In order to save an image to IsolatedStorage you need to replace this :

```
library.SavePictureToCameraRoll(fileName, e.ImageStream);
```

with this :

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile isStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream targetStream = isStore.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        // Initialize the buffer for 4KB disk pages.
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;

        // Copy the image to the local folder. 
        while ((bytesRead = e.ImageStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            targetStream.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
}
```

Then access the image the same way you've described in your original post.
Source : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202956(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_SavingToTheMediaLibraryAndIsolatedStorage

Comment: Hi! I appreciate your answer very much but I was actually intending to save to camera roll as well as retrieve from the camera roll.  I will need to look into that.  I appreciate you pointing out the difference!

Comment: I guess you could select a picture from PictureCollection retrieved from CameraRoll, this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719250/windows-phone-8-obtain-taken-photos-from-phone-library